# "Couldn't move app"

Tags: applications, external-sd, 5.1-lollipop

**First of all, this seems to be a DIFFERENT problem than the one which is often discussed.** Don't flame me. I've searched for 2-3 hours for a solution on this forum and several of the other major Android forums including Google.

The phone is a Motorola (Lenovo) XT1527, also known as "Moto E (2nd Generation) with 4G LTE" running Android 5.1. This phone is known for its tiny internal memory, 8GB with 5GB usable. It was bought DIRECTLY FROM Lenovo, not through any carrier so it is their generic GSM/LTE phone with US LTE frequencies. There is NO carrier involvement. (Sorry for the caps but I am trying to forestall incorrect answers.)

The problem is that when after installing apps designed to be moved to the SD card, some apps move and others (which have moved successfully in the past) now report "Couldn't move app." with a tappable "OK."

The common solution reported in many fora is to:

- Unmount and remove the SD card
- Mount it in a PC and delete the appropriate blah.blah.tmp.asec file
- Replace it in the phone and all will be well

Unfortunately this **does not help**. (Not to digress but it does have one minor side effect. If I try "MOVE TO SD CARD" more than once, I get the "Couldn't move app" message twice on every attempt after the first. Deleting the *.asec file results in only one message appearance for the first subsequent attempt.)

After that detailed preamble, the questions are short and simple:

1. What can I do to correct this?
2. If that's unknown, what additional information is required to diagnose the problem and how do I collect it?

I should also have specified that this does not occur for all apps. Some move, others don't. Last week Waze moved. This week it won't. I should also have specified that this problem continues to occur after backing up the phone to Google, wiping it, and re-installing all the apps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't move app. Not enough storage space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/couldnt-move-app-not-enough-storage-space-i-have-factory-reset-my-phone-in). Besides that, I have noticed that issue before. Could not move a 40MB Pinball app, even though there was enough space on my SD card.

Comment: No, this is not the same problem as " Couldn't move app. Not enough storage space." The message is distinctly different. I quoted it in its entirety above as "Couldn't move app." If I recall correctly, that problem affected a different version of Android than mine which is 5.1. However, I am more than willing to try the solution to the problem you referred to. Please post it.