# permanent storage space warning

Tags: storage, android-10

I have an UMIDIGI A3X with Android 10 (16GB internal ROM) with an 64GB SD-card, that is formatted as internal storage.

I am using 19,39GB storage but it's so poorly distributed that only 3,8 are on the SD-card.
Thus i am getting constant storage-warnings. I tried to move big apps to the external card, but that does not work (alert: low storage). I'm not sure, if it's smart tobuy a new SD-card, because [this old thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/couldnt-move-app-not-enough-storage-space-i-have-factory-reset-my-phone-in) indicates it is likely that it's not a card related problem.
There are "old" answers, that prpose to try a 32GB one, but i'm not sure if that is a good idea. Is there any other way to deal with that problem?

(If not, my plan is to buy a new 32GB card, but i would like to have full 64GB. I'm not sure what the smartest problem-solver is.)

I have tried to format the SD-card as external, but i'm also unable to move apps to the SD-card, so i tried formatting it as internal)